# Background image scrolling when background-attachment set to scroll on Android Browser

Tags: android, html, css

I've set the following css

```
.mobile-login {
    display: block;
    background: #FF0000 url('../img/mobile-form-texture.png') repeat 0 0 scroll;
}
```

When i use the Samsung Galaxy Tab's default android browser and touch to scroll, the background image respond's to my touch event and scrolls. This is a weird problem i've never faced before. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have `scroll` declared on your background.

Remove it, or, set it to `fixed`.

Comment: i think i may have wrote the question wrongly. When i scroll the whole div should move. What we have here is the background image alone moving up, when i release (stop touching the screen) then only the div moves into position